# Outh2 авторизация реализация на RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

Извините может за столь глуппый вопрос, так как столкнулся впервые с таким но хотел бы узнать как правильно делать запрос авторизацию и получения токена по протоколу oauth2 c помощью RestSharp в Web Api на asp.net core или в десктопной используя консоль. Просмотрел везде но так и не нашел как правильно делать.Ниже приведен код что имеется виду под авторизацией

```
var client = new RestClient("https://URL_address/authorize");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", $"grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_sicret}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_URL}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Так как пробую по коду который приведен выше, но так и не получается правильно. Попробовал в PostMan сделать запрос и там все получилось, но как перенисти это в код не знаю.Также бы хотелось бы узнать как передавать в redirect_url, URL адрес localhost приложения

Comment: [How to use OAuth2 in RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30133937/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 извините за мою тупость, но все равно что-то не понимаю